# javascript, problem with printing largest number entered

Tags: javascript

The program is required to terminate if 0 is entered, otherwise it will keep going. If 0 is entered i need to print to the console the largest value entered. 
Need some help fixing this code. it doesn't always print the largest number entered. Sometimes it does.

```
     var number = 1;
     var largest = 0;

 do {
       number = prompt("Enter a number other than 0 and will tell you the largest");
       if(number >= largest) {    //If largest is small, set current number 
       as largest
       largest = number;
       }
    }  while (number > 0);
       console.log("The largest number is " + largest);
```

Comment: `as largest` on its own line will cause a `SyntaxError`. Check your console.

Comment: Cast to an actual number first, else you're comparing *strings*. (your `number` is not a number)

Comment: do i need to parseInt(number) before i plug it into the if statement?

Comment: Pretty sure `Number` is preferable

Answer (score 0):

You must convert value of `prompt` to number.

```js
var number = 1;
var largest = 0;

do {

  number = prompt("Enter a number other than 0 and will tell you the largest");

  if (parseFloat(number) >= largest)
    largest = number;
  
  } while (number > 0);

console.log("The largest number is " + largest);
```

Comment: so does storing a value from prompt always turn it into a string?

Comment: yes,you must convert to number